# Format DateTime.UtcNow() with zero timezone?

Tags: c#, datetime

`DateTime.UtcNow().ToString("s")` returns `2020-02-11T23:47:49` but it's missing the zero timezone character `Z`.

Is there a way to get the output `2020-02-11T23:47:49Z` without using a custom datetime format string?

Comment: Both of them return a different string.

Comment: **[Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)**

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, no I'm wondering if I maybe missed something. But you clearly didn't think of that possibility and decided to be rude.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both both `u` or `o` to get close to what you want. You can find the complete set of formatting options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.8).

The following 3 lines:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s"));
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("u"));
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o"));
```

Output the following:

```
2020-02-11T23:54:57
2020-02-11 23:54:57Z
2020-02-11T23:54:57.6175433Z
```

Comment: You can create your own.  Follow the link to the "custom formats"

Comment: Sorry, I missed those last few words.  Review the standard formats in the docs.  If they don't suit your needs, you'll need to create a `const string` that contains your custom format.  Life is like that sometimes